# How to add/remove active class in Bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I am trying to add/remove active class in the navbar using a snipped from similar questions, however nothing happens in my case. It´s very possible I am missing out something that could not figured out so far.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active" id="dashboard">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="painel_regras">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'painel_regras' %}">Todos as Regras</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is the Javascript part**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var navContainer = document.getElementById("navbarColor01");
  var navitem = navContainer.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
  for (var i = 0; i < navitem.length; i++) {
    navitem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += " active";
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be conflicts with other elements that have the `active` class, so when you access `current[0]`, the item at index 0 is not the one in the navbar. I have replaced `document.getElementsByClassName` with `document.querySelector` to make the element more specific.

```js
var navContainer = document.getElementById("navbarColor01");
var navitem = navContainer.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
for (var i = 0; i < navitem.length; i++) {
  navitem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.querySelector("#navbarColor01 .nav-item.active");
    current.className = current.className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active" id="dashboard">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="painel_regras">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Todos as Regras</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Nathan. Thanks for replying. Unfortunately it didn´t work for me as I am still getting nothing from JS. I see it works here and I am wondering if this is something on my side thar is causing the problem. Thanks anyway for your time to help me out on this issue.

Comment: I finally found out the reason it isn´t working in my code. The code works fine when no href is defined (i.e. href="#"). In my case as you may notice I got a link to a backend in "href="{% url 'painel_regras' %}", and when it returns, the event listener doesn´t work. If I chage href to "#" it works fine. Just to let you know that.